# Enable [command] key to register as something other than [ctrl] under VMWare Fusion?

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, vmware

I'm running 10.04LTS inside VMWare Fusion on a Mac.

The <kbd>Command</kbd> key (aka <kbd>Windows</kbd> on many keyboards) is almost always behaving as if it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, even though I done anything explicit to request that behavior.

In fact, in System>Preferences>Keyboard>Layouts>Options>Alt/Win key behavior, 'default' is chosen (rather than the 'Control is mapped to Win keys' option). However, choosing other options there do not seem to change the handling of <kbd>Command</kbd>, at least not as tested in the System>Preference>Keyboard Shortcuts app. (No matter what I've tried, <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> is always detected as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> in that app.)

I've tried:

- various options under System>Preferences>Keyboard>Layouts>Options>Alt/Win key behavior
- toggling the VMWare Fusion > Preferences > KKeyboard & Mouse > Key Mappings setup which claims to map '<kbd>Command</kbd>' to '<kbd>Windows</kbd>', and restarting the VM in each position
- the xmodmap lines suggested at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MappingWindowsKey

And yet, it's clear that *all* Ubuntu apps aren't merging <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>, because in 'Terminal', <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will Copy, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will not.

If the <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Windows</kbd> key was recognized as anything else ('Super', 'Meta', 'Hyper'? I don't care as long as it's not 'Control'), then I could achieve my real goal (which happens to be enabling CMD-based cut/copy/paste in PyCharm, while leaving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>/etc available for emacs-like bindings). I think any solution which manages to make <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> appear as something other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> in Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Translating the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> within the VM is a VMware Fusion feature. I believe it can be disabled from either the VMware Fusion global preferences or the individual VM settings.

Comment: Toggling the  VMWare Fusion setting I could find -- the "VMWare Fusion > Preferences > KKeyboard & Mouse > Key Mappings" setting mentioned above -- did not help.

I doubt the VMWare settings are the key factor -- if I use 'xev' inside Ubuntu, I see that the [ctrl] and [command] keys are being recognized as different events. But other programs (including notably the standard System>Prefs>Keyboard Shortcuts tool) refuse to see them as any different. And further, now one of the things I tried seems to have caused a persistent reversing of the sense of the [caps lock] key inside the VM. Ugh.